# storing the first item of the dictionary in a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, methods

I would like to write a function that accepts a dictionary as a parameter and will store in a variable within the function the first item or the first value in the dictionary. How do I do this in Python 3?

For example:

```
random_function({'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3})
> first_item = 'a'
> first_value = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionaries by default are not ordered, so you cannot reference the 'first' dictionary item because this will always change. If you want to reference the 'first' key/value of a dictionary, you will need to use an OrderedDict data structure. This will store the order at which the values of the dictionary were entered

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def random_function(some_dict):
    first_key = list(some_dict.items())[0][0]
    first_value = list(some_dict.items())[0][1]
    print(first_key)
    print(first_value)

my_dictionary = OrderedDict({'first': 1, 'second': 2})
random_function(my_dictionary)
> first
> 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I have understood your question properly:

```
def storeValue(pDict):

    if type(pDict) is dict:
        if len(pDict) > 0:
            storedValue = pDict[pDict.keys()[0]]

    #decide what you want to do in the else cases

    return storedValue

testDict = {'a': 1,
        'b': 2,
        'c': 3}

testValue = storeValue(testDict)
```

Answer (score -1):

With **Next** you can consume manually an iterator:

```
a = dict(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4)
b=iter(a.values())
print(next(b))  # print 1
print(next(b))  # print 2
print(next(b))  # print 3
print(next(b))  # print 4
print(next(b))  # Raise 'StopIteration'. You consumed all the values of the iterator.
```

Comment: great it worked,thanks. Could you explain how it works with example like if i want to store the second value then what would i write?